# How to display different submenus?

Tags: php, menus, walker

The following main structure is given:

```
<div id="et-top-navigation">
    <nav id="top-menu-nav">
        <ul id="top-menu" class="nav">
            <li id="menu-item-102" class="menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-102">
                <a href="URL">Über uns</a>
            </li>
            <li id="menu-item-103" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-103">
                <a href="URL">Abteilungen</a>
            </li>
            <li id="menu-item-104" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-104">
                <a href="URL">Sportpark</a>
            </li>
            <li id="menu-item-105" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-105">
                <a href="URL">News</a>
            </li>
            <li id="menu-item-106" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-106">
                <a href="URL">Impressum</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

First:
Is it best practice to insert a (mega)-submenu as a child element or keep it outside the ul#top-menu?

Second:
How can I add two submenus with different html output into it (corresponding to "Über uns" and "Abteilungen")? They will contain the links, but also static content (such as contact info etc.) In the past I simply hardcoded it into the header.php, but now I would like to have the ability to change the links of the submenus in the backend on the fly. Should I register two different menus in the function.php and extend the Walker_Nav_Class? Can the Walker_Nav_Class be extended two times? If it is best practice to insert the submenus as child elements, I don't know how I can accompilish this, because the items are generated dynamically. My explanation may be a little bit messy, but I am searching for a reliable solution before I try to implement sth. like this.

EDIT:
Here is the requested markup of the different submenus as child elements.

```
<div id="et-top-navigation">
    <nav id="top-menu-nav">
        <ul id="top-menu" class="nav">
            <li id="menu-item-102" class="menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-102">
                <a href="URL">Über uns</a>
                <!-- MEGA SUBMENU#1 -->
                <div class="tg-submenuWrapper über-uns">
                    <div class="tg-submenu">
                        <div class="container tg-submenu__content">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col col--l-6">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="tg-submenu__pages tg-submenu__pages--main col col--l-4">
                                            <div class="col col--6 col--l-12">
                                                <ul class="tg-submenu__list">
                                                    -> DYNAMIC WORDPRESS LINKS HERE - FIRST ROW (UP TO 3 SIDE BY SIDE)
                                                </ul>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="tg-submenu__pages tg-submenu__pages--sub col col--l-8">
                                            <div class="col col--6">
                                                <ul>
                                                -> DYNAMIC WORDPRESS LINKS HERE - SECOND ROW
                                                </ul>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="tg-submenu__contact col col--l-6">
                                    -> STATIC HTML MARKUP GOES HERE (= THIRD ROW)
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li id="menu-item-103" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-103">
                <a href="URL">Abteilungen</a>
                    <!-- MEGA SUBMENU#2 -->
                    <div class="tg-submenuWrapper abteilungen">
                        <div class="tg-submenu">
                            <div class="container tg-submenu__content">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-lg-2">
                                        <div class="tg-submenu__item">
                                            <ul class="tg-submenu__list">
                                                -> DYNAMIC WORDPRESS LINKS GOES HERE - FIRST ROW (5 ROWS SIDE BY SIDE)
                                            </ul>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="container">
                                -> SOME STATIC CONTENT BELOW
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </li>
            <li id="menu-item-104" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-104">
                <a href="URL">Sportpark</a>
            </li>
            <li id="menu-item-105" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-105">
                <a href="URL">News</a>
            </li>
            <li id="menu-item-106" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-106">
                <a href="URL">Impressum</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you provide html output which you want to achieve?

Comment: Yes @motivast, but it would be very huge – gimme 10 minutes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is ok to put other elements as child elements. I don't see any problem with this.

To add custom elements you have to add custom metabox to menu administration. WordPress will handle saving your custom elements automatically so you don't need to worry about this. To display your custom elements you can create custom walker class or hook into `walker_nav_menu_start_el` filter. Depending on the `type` of current item you can display menu item differently.

```
/**
 * Add meta box to admin menu view
 */
function wpse_287629_add_nav_menu_meta_boxes() {
    add_meta_box( 'wpse_287629_custom', 'Custom boxes' , 'wpse_287629_nav_menu_links', 'nav-menus', 'side', 'low' );
}

add_action( 'admin_head-nav-menus.php', 'wpse_287629_add_nav_menu_meta_boxes' );

/**
 * Output custom boxes nav menu items
 */
function wpse_287629_nav_menu_links() {

    ?>
        <div id="posttype-wpse_287629" class="posttypediv">
            <div id="tabs-panel-wpse_287629" class="tabs-panel tabs-panel-active">
                <ul id ="wpse_287629-checklist" class="categorychecklist form-no-clear">
                    <li>
                        <label class="menu-item-title">
                            <input type="checkbox" class="menu-item-checkbox" name="menu-item[-1][menu-item-object-id]" value="-1"> Contact box
                        </label>
                        <input type="hidden" class="menu-item-type" name="menu-item[-1][menu-item-type]" value="wpse_287629_contact">
                        <input type="hidden" class="menu-item-title" name="menu-item[-1][menu-item-title]" value="Contact box">
                        <input type="hidden" class="menu-item-url" name="menu-item[-1][menu-item-url]" value="#">
                        <input type="hidden" class="menu-item-classes" name="menu-item[-1][menu-item-classes]" value="wpse_287629_contact-box">
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <label class="menu-item-title">
                            <input type="checkbox" class="menu-item-checkbox" name="menu-item[-1][menu-item-object-id]" value="-1"> HTML box
                        </label>
                        <input type="hidden" class="menu-item-type" name="menu-item[-1][menu-item-type]" value="wpse_287629_html">
                        <input type="hidden" class="menu-item-title" name="menu-item[-1][menu-item-title]" value="HTML box">
                        <input type="hidden" class="menu-item-url" name="menu-item[-1][menu-item-url]" value="#">
                        <input type="hidden" class="menu-item-classes" name="menu-item[-1][menu-item-classes]" value="wpse_287629_html-box">
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <p class="button-controls">
                <span class="add-to-menu">
                    <input type="submit" class="button-secondary submit-add-to-menu right" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Add to menu', 'wpse_287629' ); ?>" name="add-post-type-menu-item" id="submit-posttype-wpse_287629">
                    <span class="spinner"></span>
                </span>
            </p>
        </div>
    <?php
}

function wpse_287629_display_custom_nav_items($item_output, $item, $depth, $args) {

    if( $item->type === 'wpse_287629_contact' ) {
        // Return contact box
    }

    if( $item->type === 'wpse_287629_html' ) {
        // Return html box
    }

    return $item_output;
}

add_filter('walker_nav_menu_start_el', 'wpse_287629_display_custom_nav_items', 10, 4);
```